# Sort objects by numbers In the string

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program where objects contain numbers in the strings as following

Asian Handicap (1-3)

Asian Handicap (1-1)

Asian Handicap (0-1)

`I want to sort it as follow`

Asian Handicap (0-1)

Asian Handicap (1-1)

Asian Handicap (1-3)

Here is the code example. I tried but not sorting

```js
const transformResult = {
    "resultedEvents": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa",
            "resultedMarkets": [
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap",
                    "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa (Live)",
            "resultedMarkets": [
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap -0.5 (1-3)",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap (1-3)",
                    "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
                },
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap -0.2 (1-1)",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap (1-1)",
                    "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
                },
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap -0.2 (0-1)",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap (0-1)",
                    "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

const data= transformResult.resultedEvents.map(item => item.resultedMarkets.sort(function (itemA, itemB) {
  return itemA.newName < itemB.newName;
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Above program is not sorting as expected

`Expected`

```
{
    "resultedEvents": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa",
            "resultedMarkets": [
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap",
                    "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Football",
            "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa (Live)",
            "resultedMarkets": [
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap -0.2 (0-1)",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap (0-1)",
                    "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
                },
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap -0.2 (1-1)",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap (1-1)",
                    "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
                },
                {
                    "name": "Asian Handicap -0.5 (1-3)",
                    "newName": "Asian Handicap (1-3)",
                    "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me to correct if I am doing wrong.

I want to sort it by newName only

Comment: Nitpick: If you can do `transformResult.resultedEvents`, `transformResult` doesn't contain JSON. JSON is not an alias for JavaScript literals.

Comment: Why do you use `return itemA.newName < itemB.newName;` when you actually want `return itemA.newName > itemB.newName;`?

Comment: I am very new to coding please

Comment: Is `0-3` < `1-0`? Do you have numbers with more than one digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not make a copy of the object, so any manipulation of the nested content will change the original.
2. If you do not NEED a copy, you do not need to map but can use forEach

You seem to want to sort ascending

```js
const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(transformResult))
data.resultedEvents.forEach(item => item.resultedMarkets.sort(function(itemA, itemB) {
  if (itemA.newName > itemB.newName) return 1
  if (itemA.newName < itemB.newName) return -1
  return 0;
}));

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script>
  const transformResult = {
    "resultedEvents": [{
        "categoryName": "Football",
        "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa",
        "resultedMarkets": [{
          "name": "Asian Handicap",
          "newName": "Asian Handicap",
          "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
        }]
      },
      {
        "categoryName": "Football",
        "name": "Arsenal vs Aston Villa (Live)",
        "resultedMarkets": [{
            "name": "Asian Handicap -0.5 (1-3)",
            "newName": "Asian Handicap (1-3)",
            "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
          },
          {
            "name": "Asian Handicap -0.2 (1-1)",
            "newName": "Asian Handicap (1-1)",
            "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
          },
          {
            "name": "Asian Handicap -0.2 (0-1)",
            "newName": "Asian Handicap (0-1)",
            "meaningMinorCode": "AH "
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
```